# Print keys and values from dictionary in descending order without importing operator(Python)

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

For my assignment I'm writing a program that will take the contents of a file, store it into a dictionary, count and output the number of occurrences of each word in the file, and output the ten most frequently occurring words in descending order.

Here is my code. I didn't want to use import operator, but I'm trying to sort the contents in my dictionary. Right now I have the values printing in sorted order but not with the key in front. How do I print the key words from the dictionary, with the number of occurrences attached, in descending order?

```
done = False
while not done:
    try:
        print("ENTER A FILE NAME, IF NOT IN SAME FILE LOCATION AS PROGRAM, SPECIFY PATH")
        input_file_name = input("Please Enter the name of your text file: ")
        infile = open(input_file_name, "r")
        done = True

    except FileNotFoundError:
        done = False
        print("File not Found")


myDict = {}
file = infile.read()
line = file.split()
unwanted_chars = ".,!-_)(*&^%$#@:;'<>?/\{}[]|+=~`"

for symbol in line:
    word = symbol.strip(unwanted_chars)
    if word not in myDict:
        myDict[word] = 0
    myDict[word] = myDict[word] + 1

sortedValues = sorted(myDict.values())

print(myDict)
print(sortedValues)

infile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
sortedKeysAndValues = sorted(myDict.items(), key=lambda kv: -kv[1])
```

And then to print,

```
for k, v in sortedKeysAndValues:
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: yes this works! Could you explain this? I haven't seen this used before. Lambda is an anonymous function yes? I don't understand what kv: -kv[1] is referring to though, does it just represent keys and values? If so why is there a - in front of k?

Comment: Yeah sure, you can look at the documentation of [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) for more information but essentially, `myDict.items()` will split the dictionary up into key-value pairs. `key=lambda kv: -kv[1]` specifies the comparison key to sort the list, since you needed it in descending order, we use `-kv[1]` as `sorted()` sorts in ascending order by default and `-kv[1]` is just taking the negative of the occurrences. And yes, lambda is just an anonymous function.

Comment: Also, having just looked at the documentation for `sorted()` now, it probably makes more sense to use `key=lambda kv: kv[1]` instead and specify `reverse=True`.

Answer (score 0):

**Python 2**

```
sorted_dict = sorted([(value,key) for (key,value) in myDict.iteritems()])
```

**Python 3**

```
sorted_dict = sorted([(value,key) for (key,value) in myDict.items()])
```

Printing for both python **2** and **3**

```
print([(key, value) for value, key in sorted_dict]
```